# Not work maven dependencies in Spring MVC

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm writting my application using Intellij IDEA, maven, Spring MVC. I've added maven dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

But classes **javax.validation** and **org.hibernate.validator** cannot be found.
I try *File->Invalidate Caches / Restart...* in IntelliJ but it not works. All other dependencies work correct.

Comment: put your whole pom.xml here

Comment: you may remove above library in m2 folder so maven could download it again.

Comment: In another PC it works correctly. Later I try remove m2.

Comment: Reimport maven project

Comment: I have deleted m2 directory and reimported. Its ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- right click on `pom.xml`
- choose `Maven -> Generate sources and update folders`